# Python simple check

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I am just learning Python and I want to check if a list contains a word. When I check for the word it always returns 0, even though the function can find it and print it. But the if/else statement always return 0, when I use 2 returns as below. Can you help me?

```
def line_number(text, word):
    """
    Returns the line number (beginning with 1) where the word appears for the first time
    :param text: Text in which the word is searched for
    :param word: A word to search for
    :return: List of Line Numbers
    """
    lines = text.splitlines()
    i = 0
    for line in lines:
        i = i +1
        if word in line:
            return i
        else:
            return 0
            # print("nope")


words = ['erwachet', 'Brust', 'Wie', 'Ozean', 'Knabe']
    for word in words:
        num = line_number(wilhelm_tell, word)
        if num > 0:
            print(f"Das Word {word} findet sich auf Zeile {num}.")
        else:
            print(f"Das Wort {word} wurde nicht gefunden!")
```

Comment: What is the variable `wilhelm_tell`?

Comment: In your first loop iteration it has to return something according to your logic. Ask yourself why are you returning immediately 0 if you can't find the word.

Comment: wilhelm_tell is a text file?

Comment: Ask yourself, what happens if ***the first line*** of Guglielmo Tell doesn't contain `word`?

Comment: it returns 0 and does not keep on searching. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `return 0`  after the for loop ends and not inside the loop.

```py
def line_number(text, word):
    """
    Returns the line number (beginning with 1) where the word appears for the first time
    :param text: Text in which the word is searched for
    :param word: A word to search for
    :return: List of Line Numbers
    """
    lines = text.splitlines()
    i = 0
    for line in lines:
        i = i +1
        if word in line:
            return i
    return 0
```

The problem is the `else` statement inside the loop because it will break the loop in the first iteration.

Comment: thanks alot. I overthought the whole if/else loop. the loop will end on the first find, if its true

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're returning 0 on the first line the word is not in. So instead, you should return 0 after you looked through every line:

```
def line_number(text, word):
    """
    Returns the line number (beginning with 1) where the word appears for the first time
    :param text: Text in which the word is searched for
    :param word: A word to search for
    :return: List of Line Numbers
    """
    lines = text.splitlines()
    i = 0
    for line in lines:
        i = i +1
        if word in line:
            return i
    return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that you are returning 0 if the word is not within a line. When you use the return keyword, it will exit the function and return the value. So if a word is not within the first line of the text, it will return 0 (even though the word is present on further lines)

Here is a little example of what i think is happening:

```py
def is_element_within_list(element_to_search, some_list):
    for element in some_list:
        if element == element_to_search:
            return True
        else:
            return False


some_list = [1, 2, 3]
element_to_search = 2
print(is_element_within_list(element_to_search, some_list))
# output: False
```

We have a function that checks if an element is within a list (we could use the keyword "in", but is for the sake of the example). So, despite that `2` is within `some_list`, the function output is `False`, because the function is returning `False` on the else if the elements are no the same